# Are these two axioms of set theory say the same thing？

Tags: set-theory

Recently, I am learning set theory. I find that in some books, there is one axiom called axiom of pair which says that:

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then the doubleton $\{A,B\}$ is a set.

However, in another book, I find its edition of axiom of pair is that：

If $a$ and $b$ are two elements, then there exists a set $\{a,b\}$.

I don't know how to prove that these two axioms actually say the same thing while the former is talking about sets and the latter is talking about elements. Can anyone help me?

Comment: elements are sets in ZFC, so yes, they are the same

Comment: What is an "element" though? The ZFC axioms are based on the assumption that every object is a set. There are no "elements" other than sets. So when you say that $a,b$ are two elements, the meaning is that they are sets.

Comment: @Mark, thank you for your explanation, I used to think that sets and elements are both primitive concepts in ZFC axioms.

Comment: "ZFC" is not as uniform a thing as these comments make it sound. While the basics of what is covered are the same, there are multiple forms of the axioms that have been established over the years. I've seen some where indeed, the only possible objects are sets. But I've also seen others which do not require all objects to be sets. They don't provide any means to show the existence of non-sets (a.k.a. "ur-elements"), but one could include additional axioms to establish a theory with ur-elements without contradiction.